# AS3 Help for Numbers Change View

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to change view numbers for 15.24514 to 15.24

```
    public function jackpotstring():String {

        var myPattern:RegExp = /./; 
        var jp:Number = jackpot * denom;
        jp = Math.round(jp * 100)/100;
        jp = jp / 100;
        var s:String = String(jp);
        return s;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
public function roundTo(number:Number, decimals:int):Number {
    var roundFactor:Number = Math.pow(10, decimals)
    return Math.round(number * roundFactor) / roundFactor;
}
```

Or you can just use Number method toFixed():

```
var formattedNumber:String = someNumber.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What problems do you have with implementing my solution in your project?